# insert then update inside loop

Tags: php, mysql, performance, insert

I have a php script, I use it to be run in as cron job.

When this script running it takes about 13 minutes on 16000 user records.

**Please advice me to make this script running with the best performance.**

I need to know that if there is any problem if i put update then insert inside a loop, or insert then update inside a loop.

```
$db_conn = getDbObject('my_db');

$now_timestamp = time();

$message_text = getMessage('notify');

$users_sql = "SELECT * FROM users_tbl WHERE status = 'sub' and expire_timestamp < '{$now_timestamp}' ";

$users_result = mysql_query($users_sql,$db_conn);

while($user_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($users_result)){

    $update_user_sql = "UPDATE users_tbl SET status = 'pending' WHERE user_id = '{$user_row['user_id']}' ";

    mysql_query($insert_message_sql,$db_conn);

    $insert_message_sql = "INSERT INTO 
                                messages_tbl 
                                        (
                                            message_id ,
                                            message_text ,
                                            user_id ,
                                            status                          
                                        )
                                    VALUES 
                                        (
                                            NULL , 
                                            '{$message_text}', 
                                            '{$user_row['user_id']}',  
                                            '0',                                            
                                        )";


    mysql_query($insert_message_sql,$db_conn);

}

mysql_close($db_conn);
```

Comment: It should be nice you use sql parameters, so you can prepare the sql statement the first time and execute N of them. But I don't know how to do it in PHP. Another nice thing would be to do a limited amount of work (a maximum of records) and call it multiple times, in order to avoid request timeout, but in that case you will have to process the "next pendings" records the next time you execute it.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to know that if there is any problem if i put update then insert inside a loop, or insert then update inside a loop.

Sure this is a problem.

You should get rid of the loop and make your operations set-based:

```
INSERT
INTO    messages_tbl (message_id, message_text, user_id, status)
SELECT  NULL, '{$message_text}', user_id, '0'
FROM    users_tbl
WHERE   status = 'sub' 
        AND expire_timestamp < '{$now_timestamp}'

UPDATE  users_tbl
SET     status = 'pending'
WHERE   status = 'sub' and expire_timestamp < '{$now_timestamp}'
```